# Passing method reference to method shows error

Tags: java, java-8

I have a function which is defined as follows:

```
public static <T> T readSingleValue(MyTransaction t, String s, T alternativeVal, Function<Integer, T> rsGetter) {
    ...
    return rsGetter.apply(1);
}
```

Now I want to call this method like this:

```
readSingleValue(transaction, "select count(0) from users", 0, ResultSet::getInt);
```

whereas ResultSet::getInt() is defined as this:

```
int getInt(int columnIndex)
```

My compiler shows me following error for the parameter `ResultSet::getInt`:
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where would you get the `ResultSet` object to call `getInt` on?

Comment: Good question, I have not thought about this. Thanks

Comment: If you have variable `ResultSet rs`, you can use method reference `rs::getInt` as the last parameter to your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResultSet::getInt` is a reference to a static method, but the method is an instance method, this is the error. Another option could be:

```
public static <T> T readSingleValue(MyTransaction t, String s, T alternativeVal, Function<ResultSet, T> rsGetter)
```

and call it

```
readSingleValue(transaction, "select count(0) from users", 0, rs -> rs.getInt(1));
```

The function `Function<ResultSet, T> rsGetter` is more powerful because it can map a `ResultSet` to the desired object that can be composed from multiple columns from the database. For example, you could have

```
    readSingleValue(transaction, "select * from users where user_id = 1", null, 
        rs -> {
            User u = new User();
            u.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            u.setName(rs.getString(2));
            ...
            return u;
        });
```

Comment: You can simply use `rs::getInt`.

Comment: I think the `resultSet` is created inside the method `readSingleValue`, because he passes the sql string to the method. Why pass the sql if you already have the resultSet?